# why is my bootstrap button is not coming like the other code?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

well In my card i don't want my buttons to be to the full width of the card, I am using bootstrap 4
I Need my buttons to look like how it looks when compile this code

```
<h2 class="section-heading">A Plan for Every Dog's Needs</h2>
<p>Simple and affordable price plans for your and your dog.</p>

<div class="row">

  <div class="pricing-column col-lg-4 col-md-6">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">
        <h3>Chihuahua</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <h2 class="price-text">Free</h2>
        <p>5 Matches Per Day</p>
        <p>10 Messages Per Day</p>
        <p>Unlimited App Usage</p>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-dark" type="button">Sign Up</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="pricing-column col-lg-4 col-md-6">
    <div class="card">
```

but instead my button is taking the full width of the card
this is my code

```
<section class="white-section" id="pricing">

    <h2 class="section-heading">A Plan for Every Dog's Needs</h2>
    <p>Simple and affordable price plans for your and your dog.</p>

    <div class="row">

      <div class="pricing-column col-lg-4 col-md-6">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header">
            <h3>Chihuahua</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <h2 class="price-text">Free</h2>
            <p>5 Matches Per Day</p>
            <p>10 Messages Per Day</p>
            <p>Unlimited App Usage</p>
            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-dark" type="button">Sign Up</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="pricing-column col-lg-4 col-md-6">
        <div class="card">
```

I don't know both of the code literally look like the same, but I don't know the reason why the button is coming like this.
why is it coming like thisl, inititially I thought it is problem with the bootstrap, but when I found out that the other code works good, I don't know what is the reason.
I would appreciate anyone who  could answer this
thankyou

Comment: Both samples render the same for me (button is not full width). The only difference I see is that the second code sample is nested inside `<section class="white-section" id="pricing">`, do you have additional css? https://jsfiddle.net/bu01q2yw/

Comment: i'm getting the same result on both code.
Please make sure you installed bootstrap properly.